# TObjectList<T> memory leak?

Tags: delphi

I have this code in Delphi 7:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  T: TObjectList;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
 T := TObjectList.Create(True);
 for i := 1 to 10000 do begin
   T.Add(TPersistent.Create);
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 FreeAndNil(T);
end;
```

And this in Delphi 2009:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  T: TObjectList<TPersistent>;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
 T := TObjectList<TPersistent>.Create(True);
 for i := 1 to 10000 do begin
   T.Add(TPersistent.Create);
 end;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FreeAndNil(T);
end;
```

According to the Task Manager, when i free T in Delphi 7, all the memory that it used is freed, but in Delphi 2009, the memory is not free and even adds extra 30 kb. Am i missing something? or is there a memory leak in TObjectList in Delphi 2009?

Comment: Ugh, Delphi 2009... not for this issue which obviously is none but for 100 other reasons. Get off that version as soon as you can. Especially if you want to use generics. They are terribly broken so are many other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both versions do not leak. Your confusion stems from using the wrong tool to detect leaks. Memory managers tend to hang on to memory blocks that were recently used, and hope that they can be reused.

If you wish to detect memory leaks use the full FastMM library. That will show you that your code does not leak.

Comment: AFAIK, in one of the latest versions, *FastMM*'s `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutDown` was moved to *System.pas*, and can now be used without the explicit use of the *FastMM* unit.

Comment: That's true but there is no information beyond the number of blocks leaked. Using FastMM allows you to obtain stack traces at the point of allocoof each leaked block and many other powerful debugging tools.

Comment: sure, with the explicit fastMM you get much better diagnostics. But I find it useful for a quick check.

Answer (score 4):

Task Manager only reports the memory requested by the application through the Windows API. Delphi (just like every other compiler) has its own memory allocator that requests memory from Windows in chunks and then suballocates it as necessary. When you free a Delphi object, or a chunk of memory, it does not necessarily go back to Windows - Delphi's memory allocator simply marks the memory as free so it can be reused in subsequent memory requests. Windows knows nothing about that.

Try to create your own object and override its destructor - you can then put a breakpoint there to check that it indeed gets called.

Comment: Also note that modern Delphi versions have [`ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown) to detect *true* memory leaks from Delphi's memory allocator, as only it can know what actually constitutes a leak or not. In Delphi 7, you would have to manually install [FastMM](https://github.com/pleriche/FastMM4) to get that same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

There are no memory leaks. I tested both methods on Delphi XE6 and 10.2.3. I used: "ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := DebugHook <> 0;" and to read memory GetProcessMemoryInfo -> WorkingSetSize.